# Kodaira decomposition of 1-form on a Real manifold

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-forms, hodge-theory

I recently stumbled across the Hodge decomposition theorem, which states that on any compact orientable manifold, for any form the following holds
$$
\omega = \text{d}\alpha + \delta \beta + \gamma
$$
Where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are uniquely determined forms, $d$ is the exterior derivative, and $\delta = \star d \star$ the Hodge coderivative. What i don't understand is whether there exist a similar decomposition on non compact manifolds, such as $\mathbb{R}^n$, and if that is the case, if we can find $\alpha$ by solving the following equation(in the case $\omega$ is a 1-form), 
$$
\Delta \alpha = (\delta d + d \delta) \alpha = \delta \omega
$$
The equations above works for 1-forms if the Hodge decomposition holds, 
since 
$$
\Delta \alpha = (\delta d + d \delta) \alpha =\delta d\alpha =   \delta \omega \overset{\text{Hodge}}{=} \delta d\alpha
$$

I would like to understand if this way of finding $\alpha$ can work on non-compact spaces.

Comment: Note that on the simplest non-compact manifold, $\Bbb R$, every $1$-form is exact. In particular, the harmonic $1$-forms $(ax+b)dx$ are also exact, and so there's no direct sum decomposition. (Here I'm thinking of defining $\delta$ by an $L^2$ pairing with smooth objects with compact support. So $\delta(f(x)\,dx) = -f'(x)$ and $\Delta(f(x)\,dx) = -f''(x)\,dx$.)